# MongoDB aggregate and match the returned keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The thing is, i'm writing some code for getting user messages from my DB. DB has **sent_to**, **sent_by**, **message** keys and the command i'm following to get the data keys is

```
db.users_messages.aggregate({$group: {_id: {to: "$sent_to", by: "$sent_by"}}})
```

This returns the list of all the **sent_to** and **sent_by** Users_IDs. Now let's suppose if *user1* has sent the message to *user2* and also *user2* has replied back to *user1*, i want it to return only *user1* for *user2*, not *user2* for *user1*. And when i'm checking this thing later, then i'm left with pagination thing, because i'm applying **$limit** on aggregation.
Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is no small feat and I think the real solution here is to include some more meta-data on your documents, specifically to represent who the conversation is "between" in a consistent way.

What I mean by this, is the "key" needs to be unique for the conversation, no matter who was sending the message or who was receiving. Consider these two basic documents.

```
{ "from": 1, "to": 2, "between": [1,2] },
{ "from": 2, "to": 1, "between": [1,2] }
```

Where in each case the "from" and "to" are unique identifiers for each "user" that will always sort in a specific way. The "between" data is always sorted to remain in the same order, this could be done in code as you create or via "upsert" functionality with the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier and [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/), but the point is to keep that "unique" key to use in determining which documents belong to the same grouping.

It is possible to do with the aggregation framework alone, but it is really unnecessary hoop jumping when you consider you could just maintain that on your documents:

```
db.converse.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "from": { "$push": "$from" },
        "to": { "$push": "$to" }  
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "between": { "$setUnion": [ "$from", "$to" ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$between" },
    { "$sort": { "between": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "between": { "$push": "$between" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$between",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

In in versions earlier than MongoDB 2.6 that does not have something like [**`$setUnion`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) available, combine to an array in a different way:

```
db.converse.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "from": 1,
        "to": 1,
        "type": { "$const": [ "from", "to" ] },
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "between": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "from" ] },
                    "$from",
                    "$to"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$between" },
    { "$sort": { "between": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "between": { "$push": "$between" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$between",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

In each case, there is a reasonable amount of paranoia being exhibited as "sets are not ordered". They may happen to come out that way, but you probably cannot count on that.

The principles are basically the same here, by creating a uniquely ordered "list" in the "between" element and then using that as the grouping key. From the above example document, and ignoring the existing between field, the process will return just one document with a count of "two" as shown:

```
{ "_id" : [ 1, 2 ], "count" : 2 }
```

So it really makes a lot of sense to maintain this sort of data on the document as you create or modify them. In that way the grouping becomes simple as the "unique key" is already identified

Comment: I like your suggestion, but seems a long way.

Comment: @Ravi A long way? I think the aggregation is the "long way". If this is the sort of thing you are intending to do then you are better off maintaining the data in the document. The aggregation shows that it is "possible" not that you "should" be doing it. You "should" have that information in the document without projecting it each time.

Comment: Since you're here, one more question, after adding something like this `{ "from": 2, "to": 1, "between": [1,2] }` and `{ "from": 2, "to": 1, "between": [1,3] }` , is there a way i can call distinct on between field to get whole separate arrays, not all distinct items (like when i call distinct on this field it **returns array: [1,2,3]**)?

Comment: Don't mind, i got the answer for last one. Thanks for your time :)